# Mongoid syntax for querying based on several sets of attributes

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Assuming I want to get 3 documents which fit one of these attributes

Class Question:

```
name=>a, topic=>b
name=>c, topic=>d
name=>e, topic=>f
```

What is the appropriate syntax for mongoid to get these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mongoid query syntax](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/):

```
Model.any_of({:name => a, :topic => b}, 
             {:name => c, :topic => d}, 
             {:name => e, :topic => f})
```